# Centering main content column with max-width

Tags: css, center

The main content column of my website is too wide for 1920x1080 resolution, so I'm trying to limit the size by using the max-width property, but when I do that the column is no longer centered. So every time I reduce the maximum width (let's say from 1600 to 1400px), the main content gets "chopped off" on the right side instead of being centered. Here's screenshot to demonstrate:

[image: Example]

Note: I can't use margins for this because it will make the column too small on lower resolution devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

`margin: 0 auto;`

This sets the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties to `auto` which centers a fixed width element (such as your `max-width` element).

Now, as for lower screen stuff, you should try to reset the margins on lower screen devices with a media query.

Comment: @GlebOleinik - then you're not doing it right: http://jsfiddle.net/bgfu5b7v/ Any chance you're `float`ing it? You can't center something that is `float`ed left.

Comment: Ok you're right, it works now. But now it pushed the sidebar on the right side down to the bottom.

Comment: @GlebOleinik - there's a lot more at play here that can only be illustrated through simplistic fiddles, you're going to have to show us the code your working with.

Comment: Here's the relevant code:                                                                      .site-content {
 margin: 20px 100px 0 100px;
}
.content-area {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1250px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.site-main {
 margin-right: 330px;
 overflow: auto;
}
.widget-area {
 width: 315px;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 200px;
 font-size: 0.9em;   -  Widget-area is the sidebar. There's enough space for it to fit on the right but it drops down below.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I kinda fixed it with a ghetto solution that seems to be working ok. Spent so much time on this small thing, should've asked earlier.